# "Snap" but it's not photography lingo

Tags: terminology

I first heard the term "Snap" in a television drama a year or so ago from a recovering drug addict-turned rogue police detective.  I think it is a form of verbal exclamation, similar to "wow" or "Yeah!"  Does anyone know how recently this term/expression was coined?  Also, is my idea of the meaning correct or is there a different meaning (other than like snapping a stick in half)?  Here's an example.  "Snap.  I just realized where I saw that guy before."  Another example.  A young boy finally learns how to tie his shoes himself.  His youthful father exclaims, "Snap.  See, I told you it's nothin' so hard."

Comment: http://www.edrants.com/the-mysterious-origins-of-oh-snap/

Answer (score 1):

I have only heard Snap as an exclamation when someone finds they have a similarity with another person. I believe it comes from the card game Snap, where if a player puts down the same card as the previous player the first one to say “Snap” takes the cards.